# Request Permission Before onMapReady

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, maps, registerforactivityresult

I'm using following function to request permission. The problem is if I use it in onMapReady it's giving this error message `"MapsActivity@cab019a is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED."` and If i use it in onCreate() this time `it's giving mMap lateinit property has not been initialized` How can i solve that.
Where I need to use mMap.isMyLocationEnabled

```
private fun requestPermission(){

    val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"PERMISSION GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                mMap.isMyLocationEnabled=true


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"SHUTTING DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
        }

    when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) -> {
            Toast.makeText(this,"PERMISSION'S ALREADY GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            mMap.isMyLocationEnabled=true


        }
        else -> {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This error is thrown when you declare a property as lateinit and don't initialize it before using it.

Comment: I know it but  i need to learn how to prevent from that.